# Why Wordpress does not create pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, buddypress

I just installed a new theme. I bought the Salutation theme, installed it, ok. But, whenever I create a page through the menu (pages --> add new), and then I try to publish it and visualize it, the page doesn't exist! It shows a 404 error:

> The requested URL /public_html/pagename/ was not found on this server.

I also used the import option to import 'static blocks', which are necessary for the theme. The theme comes with a demo, which has another 50 more pages, but all of them give the same error (404 NOT FOUND)!

My guess is that is a problem with a permalink or something like that (I need to use the BuddyPress plugin)....But help me!

Answer (score 2):

Try going to Settings->Permalinks and saving the settings (changing is not necessary). This should flush your permalinks. If that doesn't work, you should look at your .htaccess file and see what is inside it. If it looks dramatically different from these samples: https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess try to see what is editing it and you will have to deactivate whatever that is.

Comment: THANKS! I found the problem! I needed to activate the "rewrite_module" on my Apache server (I'm using WAMP) for it to work!

Answer (score -2):

Every Page you create in wordpress can only be accessed by creating a Menu alias for that page.

**Try This**

1. Login to your dashboard
2. Goto Appearance >> Menu
3. Look for the page you created and add it to the Site Menu
4. Save the changes on the Menu
5. Goto the Main Site, refresh the site and test your menu

**Note that:** you can also create other types of menu like "Custom Links" (pointing to the Page or external sites). This helps only when you've changed the permalink of the page or when you know the page id